# Interperting const points with typedefs

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, declaration, typedef

I am trying to understand this const and pointers.

```
typedef cu::Op const * operation_t; 
typedef operation_t const * const_operation_ptr_t;
```

Is `operation_t` a pointer to a `const cu::Op` object?

And so on the second line, if you substitute `operation_t` you get `cu::Op const * const *`.

Does this mean that `const_operation_ptr_t` is a constant pointer (its address cannot change) which is pointing to a constant object whose value cannot be changed?

Comment: BTW: `using operation_t= cu::Op const *;` looks more readable for me as the outdated C syntax. And using the normal ordering of qualifiers make it more readable: `using operation_t= const cu::Op  *;`

Comment: Some told me, read it right to left. So it is: a (non-const) pointer to const operation_t

Answer (score 0):

The typedef name `operation_t` denotes a non-constant pointer to a constant object of the type `cu::Op`.

```
typedef cu::Op const * operation_t;
```

The typedef name `const_operation_ptr_t` denotes a non-constant pointer to a constant pointer of the type `cu::Op const *`.

```
typedef operation_t const * const_operation_ptr_t;
```

To make the both introduced pointer types as types of constant pointers you need to write

```
typedef cu::Op const * const operation_t;
```

and

```
typedef operation_t const * const const_operation_ptr_t;
```

A more simple example. These two declarations

```
const int *p;
```

and

```
int const *p;
```

are equivalent and declare a non-constant pointer to an object of the type `const int`.

This declaration

```
int * const p = &x;
```

declares a constant pointer to a non-constant object of the type int.

These declarations

```
const int * const p = &x;
```

and

```
int const * const p = &x;
```

are equivalent and declare a constant pointer to a constant object of the type const int.